# How to achieve like in asp.net that button is aware which user I want to edit or delete from HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have in HTML table users data, one row for every user (username, password, name, last_name, I have id from sql table but I don't show id). I need to add for every row two buttons ( edit and delete). How to achieve like in asp.net that button is aware which user I want to edit or delete ? If something help I already have array of users in JavaScript ( Dojo for declaring object user ). Can anybody give me idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Give an ID for every row like `< td>< a id="65" href="">Delete < /a> < /td>`  and get that id ( with JS, get the value of that) to process the form